# firebase-admin: FieldValue.arrayUnion not working NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase-admin v11.2.1

I can update a title in a project using:

```js
if (title) {
  batch.update(projectRef, {
    title
  })
}
```

But I cannot add an item to an array using:

```js
batch.update(projectRef, {
   admins: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(`/users/${admin}`)
})
```

The error is being caught in a catch block, but the error comes back as an empty object

```js
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err })
}
```

resolves as:

```js
{
    "error": {}
}
```

Everything I read doing what I want to do point to arrayUnion as the answer, but it's not working for me. Any help is appreciated - thank you.

Edit: Here is the way a project is modeled.

[image]

I'm on another codebase too where arrayUnion is NOT working. I get the error:

```
const ids = members.map((member) => member.id);

await projectRef.update({
   members: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...ids)
)}

error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'arrayUnion')
```

Though I'm in another codebase where arrayUnion is working exactly like you'd expect (firebase-admin version 9.8):

```
 if (role === 'admin') {
    batch.update(organisationRef, {
      invitedAdmins: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)
  })
}
```

So very stumped

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot (from the Firestore console) of a document you are trying to update?

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen - I updated the question! Thanks for the extra set of eyes. I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: Hmm... that looks fine to me at first glance, and I don't really see where the code would be wrong. How did you add the existing values to `admins` and `members`?Did they come from this same code?

Comment: Different code base but same syntax. The other codebase is using an older version of firebase-admin, but I tried rolling back versions - didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
const { FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

FieldValue.arrayUnion(userId)
```